# OutputStreamWrite is not appending to file

Tags: android, file, outputstream, fileoutputstream

My OutputStreamWrite refuses to append to my file.  It only overwrites the first line constantly.

The String lightRowValues are sent from another method that goes through a table and gets one row at a time, sends that row data here, where that row is written to this file.  Then the method loops back and gets the next row. SO I should have a list of rows but instead only have one line of the very last entry.

```
public static void appendToLtCSV(String lightRowValues, String CSVFinalFileName){

        try {
            csvfos = new FileOutputStream(CSVFinalFileName, true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OutputStreamWriter sensorCSVWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(csvfos);
        try {
            sensorCSVWriter.append(lightRowValues);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sensorCSVWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

I have set the append flag to true and still the same problem....

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a very long first line?

Comment: If you don't have any exceptions in your LogCat, based on your code the only result would be to write everything on the first line. Not replace old text but to add it to the end of the line. You said that only the last call is saved. I was asking if not all calls are saved but only on first line.

Comment: Oh I get it.  No all calls are saved but the first line is constantly over written instead of appending. So the final result is simply one entry and that is the last row of data detected.

Comment: Since this particular method is part of a loop, you think the fact that I am opening it and closing it is what is causing the problem?

Comment: The fact that you are NOT closing csvfos might be the problem.